# Is there a procedure to creating JUnit test cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm fairly new to Java development and today was the first time I paired program to create a test case. They were kind enough to talk out-loud what they were thinking to explain why certain things were being done (e.g. creating a constructor with arguments instead of just having a default constructor, etc).

While I will probably retain 40% of what I saw/heard today I was wondering if there was a set of steps/guidelines to follow, where the end result is a test case that would be a good starting point. I know the usual responses of

1. every shop has their own standard,
2. there are personal preferences and tools,
3. depends if the test is for a class you own versus legacy, etc.

Either way, I figured and ask SO members.

Here is a snippet from some of the notes I took to show what I had in mind, in terms of responses.

1. Using Mockito, you cannot mock objects that are being created with methods, therefore try and get a constructor to take those objects. This would allow you to mock them and then pass them to the method for easier testing.
2. Mockito does not handle static methods, but you can create a wrapper class that invokes the static method. Now, this new wrapper class does not use any static methods and the class your testing will use it instead of the static method. This now allows you to use when/thenReturn without having to handle the static method directly.
3. When mocking, declare the variables that will be used by all test cases at class level. Then mock those classes within setUp(); this approach ensures the commonly used mocks are always is a known state and where not modified by a previous test.
4. Can't be said enough, use good variable names (e.g. listWithOneCar, listWithNoCars, etc)
5. Since Test cases are sometimes based off a truth table, try to include that in your test method names (e.g. ensureCanDrive_Car_0_withValidKey_0(), ensureCanDrive_Car_1_withValidKey_1(), etc). This should help you visually scan if you've captured the bulk of test cases with a quick visual scan. Once done, just add edge cases.
6. 'verify' is under used, try to use more of it in your test cases.
7. Individual test cases should only have code that differs between test cases and no repeating code. This makes it easier to understand and maintain/expand.

You get the idea.
These are just from my notes, but I was wondering if anyone had a list that's evolved?

Comment: This would probably be better served on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).  Feel free to holler at a mod to have it moved.

Comment: Congrats, you seem to work with a good team, although I disagree on 'verify' and have the impression you might be using Mockito to much. Stay away from PowerMock (recommended in some answers) it's powerful, but it just covers up design smells.

Answer (score 1):

You have very different things in your list. And even for one of the topics a 'complete' list is probably not really possible. Most would make up a book, possible multiples. So here is my list of books (and other documentation) that make together a somewhat complete list.

- Some seem to be about general good coding practices. For example the recommendation to use dependency injection via constructor (#1); The importance of good names (#4). It is hard to make a complete list about those, but there are some important books. I recommend

  - Clean Code by Robert C. Martin
  - The Pragmatic Programmer by Andrew Hunt and David Thomas
  - Effective Java by Joshua Bloch
- Some are about the limitations of Mockito, just go through the documentation and some blog posts about it. You might also want to look at PowerMock, which tries to fixes some (most?) technical limitations of Mockito and other mocking frameworks. Just reading what they did will improve your understanding of Mockitos limitations.
- Some are about designing tests, making code testable and so on. You might consider the following books:

  - xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code by Gerard Meszaros
  - Test Driven: TDD and Acceptance TDD for Java Developers by Lasse Koskela
  - Test Driven Development: By Example by Kent Beck

Answer (score 1):

You're focusing on one aspect of unit testing, which is mocking.  You mock when you can't (or don't) want to test a sliver of that code - such as a database query or a logging utility.

In my experience, unit testing comes in two flavors: integration and unit tests.

The big thing is, with either flavor of unit test, you have to understand:

- What the behavior is of the method on the *happy path*, and
- what the behavior is at edge cases.

When writing unit tests, I will make use of mocking libraries like Mockito, but I don't merely exclude myself to that.  There are times when using Mockito isn't appropriate for the test you want to do (99 times out of 100, it's in an integration test.  Don't do that.), but it's handy for when I only want to mimic behavior from a heavy bean/object/DAO for either happy path or edge case tests.

My preference with tests is to arrange them into three distinct sections:

- My givens, which comprise of setting up the method to be tested, including behavior while mocking,
- my "when I do this" clause, which is essentially just executing the method, and
- my verification step, which involves me testing one aspect of my results.

As a for-instance, let's say I wanted to test the behavior of this method.

```
public List<String> shortenNamesFromDatabase(final int maxLength) {
    List<String> names = dao.executeQuery("SELECT name from dbNames");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String name : names) {
        result.add(name.substring(0, maxLength);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have a call to the database, and some transformation logic.  I don't want to bother with validating the database information *at this layer*, so I'll mock it out.  In an integration test, I make certain that the calls are made to the database, which gets me every name from the database.

```
//happy path test!
@Test
public void shortenNamesFromDatabase_namesAreOnly3CharactersLong() {
    //given
    final int length = 3;
    List<String> dbResult = Arrays.asList("Alpha","Beta", "Gamma", "Del", "Zeta12345");
    Dao daoMock = mock(Dao.class);
    when(daoMock.executeQuery("SELECT name from dbNames")).thenReturn(dbResult);
    SomeClass testObj = new SomeClass();

    //when
    List<String> result = testObj.shortenNamesFromDatabase(length);

    //then
    for(String name : result) {
        assertTrue("Name was too long!", length <= name.length());
    }
}
```

Suppose now I want to test some edge case behavior.  If I set the max length to zero, I'd expect a whole bunch of empty strings.  Not ideal, but I'd better ensure that the behavior at an edge case is what I expect it to be.

```
//edge-case-why-would-you-ever-do-this-for-real test
@Test
public void shortenNamesFromDatabase_zeroLengthStringsTransformed() {
    //given
    final int length = 0;
    List<String> dbResult = Arrays.asList("Alpha","Beta", "Gamma", "Del", "Zeta12345");
    Dao daoMock = mock(Dao.class);
    when(daoMock.executeQuery("SELECT name from dbNames")).thenReturn(dbResult);
    SomeClass testObj = new SomeClass();

    //when
    List<String> result = testObj.shortenNamesFromDatabase(length);

    //then
    for(String name : result) {
        assertTrue("Name was WAY too long!", length <= name.length());
    }
}
```

Notice how the tests didn't really change?  That's a *good* thing.  With unit tests, you should only really be asserting or validating one thing at a time.  Making major changes to test one or two edge cases might be a code smell.

When writing tests, be wary of the following:

- **Code smells:  If your code is tough to unit test, you should consider refactoring.**  This will make the testing effort easier and your code much simpler to maintain.
- **Don't get mock happy.  Only mock the things you do not need to verify.**  I don't need to verify anything from the database; not the length of the query, not that I got the exact names I wanted, anything - so I mocked it out.  What I *did* need to verify was that the transformation took place appropriately.
- **Follow common practices with regards to test-driven development, defect-driven testing, and plain-ol'-unit-testing.**  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is a good place to start, but there are books and flash cards on the subject matter.